# Making whole table row linkable with JQuery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html-table, click

Here is HTML markup of 2 rows from my huge table (which generated by PHP and applied Datatables after that)

```
<tr url="?page=item&id=850">

    <td class="item_id"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" method="post" value="850" class="checkbox"/>    850</td>

    <td> 9007</td>

    <td style="text-align:center">BK</td>

    <td style="text-align:center">41</td>

    <td style="text-align:center" id="qt">1</td>

    <td style="text-align:center">7</td>

    <td style="text-align:center">11</td>

    <td>09.02.2012</td>

</tr>
```

And here is second row

```
<tr url="?page=item&id=587">

   <td class="item_id"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" method="post" value="587" class="checkbox"/>    587</td>

   <td> 779-59</td>

   <td style="text-align:center">BR</td>

   <td style="text-align:center">37</td>

   <td style="text-align:center" id="qt">2</td>

   <td style="text-align:center">15</td>

   <td style="text-align:center">14</td>

   <td>08.02.2012</td>

</tr>
```

Function below works for 90% rows. I really have no idea why this script works for second row from examples but doesn't do anything for first row. These 2 rows are nearly same.

```
$("td").not('.item_id').click(function(){
    window.open ($(this).closest("tr").attr("url"));
});
```

How do you think, what can cause this problem?

Comment: can you setup a jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use this which will attach `click` handler on `tr` and ignore if clicked on `checkbox` or its containing cell. Try this.

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    window.open($(this).attr("url"));
});

$("td.item_id").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Alertnatively you can also use `event.target` to check if it is `checkbox` don't do any this.

```
$("tr").click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is(':checkbox') && !$(e.target).is('.item_id')){
        window.open($(this).attr("url"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try both the approaches?

Comment: is the `url` attribute valid markup?  You might be experiencing issues because jquery works best against valid HTML

Comment: yes. I can give you access to the website, if you want to take a look at. Please join chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7566/jquery-issue

Comment: @shanabus - You can add any attribute and retrieve it using `attr` method even if HTML validators don't pass them.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this piece:

```
$("td").not('.item_id').click(function(){
  ...
});
```

But could this piece be updated to perform better?

```
window.open ($(this).closest("tr").attr("url"));
```

Also, does the property `url` validate?  You may want to use data attributes for a more predictable experience. Maybe this would work better:

```
<tr data-url="">
  ...
</tr>
```

with your window open even like this:

```
window.open( $(this).parent().attr("data-url") );
```

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zuhrx/

Comment: `$(this).parent().data("url") );`

Comment: Thanks @Richard, even better!

Answer (score 0):

its working [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9EYA2/1/) something else is wrong. Are you wrapping up the code in `ready` handler?

Comment: yes. it's in ready. please join discussion http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7566/jquery-issue